# How to assign a value to all rows based on condition of one row? (see details)

Tags: sql, oracle, case, filtering

I have a table that looks like this:

| Category | Sub Category | Calculation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Furniture | Chair | 1 |
| Furniture | Table | 1 |
| Stationery | Pen | 0 |
| Stationery | Pencil | 0 |

I'm trying to come up with the third column 'Calculation' which will check for 'Table' in the data and whichever category has 'Table' in it's sub-category, all rows of that category will be 1.

I wrote a query like this:

> CASE WHEN select category in (select category from table where sub-category='Table')
> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Calculation

The above works but it increases the runtime of query from 1 min to 50 mins and it times out at times. Is there a less intensive way of writing the above query? The only condition is that whenever 'Table' comes up then all the rows belonging to parent 'Category' will be 1 under Calculation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options is to use EXISTS in CASE expression:

```sql
WITH
    tbl (CATEGORY, SUB_CATEGORY) AS
        (
            Select 'Furniture',   'Chair'   From Dual Union All
            Select 'Furniture',   'Table'   From Dual Union All
            Select 'Stationery',  'Pen'     From Dual Union All
            Select 'Stationery',  'Pencil'  From Dual 
        )
Select    CATEGORY, SUB_CATEGORY, 
          CASE  WHEN EXISTS(Select 1 From tbl Where CATEGORY = t.CATEGORY And SUB_CATEGORY = 'Table') 
                THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
          END "CALCULATION"
From      tbl t
Order By  CATEGORY, SUB_CATEGORY

CATEGORY   SUB_CATEGORY CALCULATION
---------- ------------ -----------
Furniture  Chair                  1
Furniture  Table                  1
Stationery Pen                    0
Stationery Pencil                 0
```

Another option that could be faster:

```sql
Select    t.CATEGORY, t.SUB_CATEGORY, Nvl(t2.CALC, 0) "CALCULATION"
From      tbl t
Left Join (Select CATEGORY, 1 "CALC" From tbl Where SUB_CATEGORY = 'Table' Group By CATEGORY) t2 ON(t2.CATEGORY = t.CATEGORY)
Order By  t.CATEGORY, t.SUB_CATEGORY
```

Comment: Hi, I intend to use this in a JOIN Clause as part of ON. I see that this is also performance intensive. It takes up more time than my  query in the description

Comment: @PrashanthChitrambalam Just posted an alternative...

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I had to modify it a bit to accommodate my code. Thanks a bunch! All the answers were useful, the latest edit here was the least cost intensive that i check using Explain Plan

Answer (score 0):

We can use `COUNT()` as an analytic function here:

```sql
SELECT Category, SubCategory,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN SubCategory = 'Table' THEN 1 END) OVER
                 (PARTITION BY Category) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Calculation
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Category, SubCategory;
```

Assuming that the `Table` subcategory would occur at most once in a given category, the above can be simplified to:

```sql
SELECT Category, SubCategory,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN SubCategory = 'Table' THEN 1 END) OVER
                 (PARTITION BY Category) AS Calculation
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Category, SubCategory;
```

Comment: I get a "group function is not allowed here" when I try to run this query

Comment: Hi, I plan to use this in a join clause as one of the ON conditions. Because of COUNT, I see a group function is not allowed here error. Is there a way it works in a ON clause